# Catching exceptions from all threads?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Recently I used a [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) in one of my programs. Basically one can say that the code included in the `Task` is executed in another thread. An exception was thrown in that thread, however I never noticed that, because Eclipse didn't show it (at least not in the console).

So, how to make sure I am informed about the exceptions of all threads?

Thanks for any hint on this!

**Update:** I am wondering if there is a way that does not involve code modifications / adaptions - because one can easily forget that. Any setting in Eclipse for that?

Comment: You can set an UncaughtExceptionHandler in a Thread to catch exceptions.  (I'm not aware of a Task class in Java.)

Comment: Thanks guys, reflecting your answers I updated my question.

Comment: Well, I would expect that the Eclipse debugger will, with appropriate settings, show you the exceptions that occur in all threads.

Comment: @HotLicks: You you know how to configure Eclipse for that? I tried http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/353989/ but that assumes you see a suspended thread in the debug view, which isn't even the case for me.

Comment: No, I avoid using Eclipse as much as possible.  But you very likely need to set a breakpoint in the UncaughtExceptionHandler.

Answer (score 0):

If by saying

> I am wondering if there is a way that does not involve code modifications / adaptions - because one can easily forget that.

you mean, that you could forget to code/set it for every Thread, then it is not the case.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler
```

is a static method, so you set it only once for the whole java application. Any uncaught exception on any thread will end up in that method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html